# Does the statistics sample rate impact the query planner's use of JIT compilation?

Tags: postgresql

The `pg_stats` table reveals that PostgreSQL stores a histogram when collecting statistics. This means that PostgreSQL can come up with an estimate of how many rows a filter will return by counting the number of histogram buckets that contain the filter's value. You can increase the number of histogram buckets with the `ALTER TABLE ... SET STATISTICS` which means that PostgreSQL can get even more precise (estimate fewer rows) about a filter's selectivity.

The query planner estimates the total amount of work that needs to be done to execute the query and compares that to a threshold to see if JIT query compilation should be done. Does this estimate include the row count estimates that PostgreSQL maintains for filter selectivity purposes? Would increasing the statistics sample size let the query planner make better decisions about when the performance benefit of JIT compilation outweighs the startup time of JIT compilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which means that PostgreSQL can get even more precise (estimate fewer rows) about a filter's selectivity.

More precise estimates of row counts could be either higher or lower than the less precise estimate.  If we knew ahead of time which way more precision would go, we could (probably) do something to make it more accurate without needing more histogram bins.

Yes, the row count estimates are an important part of the total cost estimate, and that is what gets compared to jit_above_cost.  So changing the stats target can change the JIT decision, although it is hard to predict ahead of time which way the change will be.  For that matter, keeping the stats target the same and just redoing the random sample (by ANALYZE) could also change the decision.

Note that jit_above_cost is a very loose heuristic in the first place.  (And  I would argue quite a broken one--cost estimates are often dominated by IO estimates, and why would estimated IO time be used to decide whether to JIT or not?  That makes not sense, except in the context that the cost estimates are not being tracked separately and we don't want to change that just to make jit_above_cost more sane)